# Can't load Amazon Web Service (AWS) S3 libraries on Android Studio

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Well, I've just tried to include AWS library in Android Studio. I was trying to send data to my S3 server from my mobile app, but I couldn't.

This is the build.gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile (group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.257'){ transitive = true }
    ...
}
```

This is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="...">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    ...
    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is an Activity.java:

```
package ...;
...
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.orhanobut.logger.Logger;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
...
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ...
    public void sendData(View v)
    {
        AmazonS3 s3client;
        File file;
        final String bucketName     = "************************";
        final String keyName        = "********************";
        final String secretKey      = "****************************************";

        try
        {
            file = new File(uri.getPath());
            s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
                (
                    new BasicAWSCredentials(keyName, secretKey)
                )
            ).build();
            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file));//~ */
        }
        catch (NoClassDefFoundError|IllegalStateException|IllegalArgumentException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (AmazonServiceException ase)
        {
            StringBuilder str_builder_error_mensaje = new StringBuilder("");

            ase.printStackTrace();
            str_builder_error_mensaje.append("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.");
            str_builder_error_mensaje.append("\nError Message:    ").append(ase.getMessage());
            str_builder_error_mensaje.append("\nHTTP Status Code: ").append(ase.getStatusCode());
            str_builder_error_mensaje.append("\nAWS Error Code:   ").append(ase.getErrorCode());
            str_builder_error_mensaje.append("\nError Type:       ").append(ase.getErrorType().name());
            str_builder_error_mensaje.append("\nRequest ID:       ").append(ase.getRequestId());
            Logger.d(str_builder_error_mensaje.toString());
        }
        catch (AmazonClientException ace)
        {
            StringBuilder str_builder_error_mensaje = new StringBuilder("");

            ace.printStackTrace();
            str_builder_error_mensaje.append("Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered an internal error while trying to communicate with S3, such as not being able to access the network.");
            str_builder_error_mensaje.append("\nError Message:    ").append(ace.getMessage());
            Logger.d(str_builder_error_mensaje.toString());
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then I get this error message when I execute it on the emulator:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:35)
W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:32)
W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:64)
```

I haven't been able to load the library of AWS in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [AWS Android setup docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html) you should be linking the `aws-android-sdk` files (not the `aws-java-sdk` files).